# AWS Key error on mounting on EFS from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, configuration, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount a directory that is on my EC2 bastion to AWS EFS using the mount command. I'm using EFS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-access-points.html#mount-with-access-point) and trying the following command,

```
   sudo mount -t efs -o tls,iam,accesspoint=fsap-xxx fs-xxx: /myDirThatINeedToMountOnRoot
```

Upon doing so, I'm getting,

```
AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key are not found in AWS credentials file (/root/.aws/credentials), config file (/root/.aws/config), from ECS credentials relative uri, or from the instance security credentials service
```

Moreover, I've also check ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config

All is on the place. Any guidance please?

Comment: `~` means `home` while it's expecting credentials and config in `/root/.aws` you have both in your home directory. Move `.aws` to your root(/root).

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:

1. Set up an IAM user (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html); Create an access key (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey))
2. Add a policy to the IAM user that allowsAmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html)
3. On the EC2 inastance install the AWS CLI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Then:
With the Access key on hand, on the EC2 run aws configure and set the credentials (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

This will save the credential file it's looking for; however, the credential files gets in the user's home directory (.aws/). Therefore, move or copy the .aws directory from /home to /root

Answer (score 0):

Remove *iam* option in given cmd.

Your command will look like this ->

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=fsap-xxx fs-xxx: /myDirThatINeedToMountOnRoot
```